# Substitute values in rows - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Every week I end up making a list of contacts that we need to send sms to, but it turns out that some numbers are missing 9 and there I always need to fix the numbers that gave an error and this ends up being laborious. I started studying pandas now so I still have several doubts. What I want to do is read the column phones and if the number of characters in that number is less than 11, which is 2 of the ddd plus 9 of the phone, it adds 9. I did a test with a cycle and it worked the replacement . But now I don't know how to implement this in pandas so that it will replace those values ​​in the dataframe. Can you help me?

This is the cycle I did, the prints were just to check if it worked.

```
for i in dados.iloc[:,3]:
  if len(str(i))<11:
    print(i)
    a = str(i)
    novo = a[:2]+'9'+a[2:]
    print('depois')
    print(int(novo))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn your snippet into a function and use `apply`

```
def add_nine(row):
    if len(str(row))<11:
        print(row)
        a = str(row)
        novo = int(a[:2]+'9'+a[2:])
        print(int(novo))

df['my_col'] = df['my_col'].apply(add_nine)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks!!!, I just had to add an else statement to return the number in case of the if statement is not satisfeid. But now it is  everything working perfectly, thanks again!